# saving state of checkboxes in android

Tags: android

I am trying to save the checkboxes using shared preferences. However...random check boxes are getting selected. Please help me debug the code...
basically three checkboxese are created but im not being able to save them...

```
    package com.isit.finale;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.Menu;

public class History extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    CheckBox c1;
    CheckBox c2;
    CheckBox c3;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);
    c1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    c2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    c3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        loadSavedPreferences();
        }



    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean c1Val= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
    boolean c2Val= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
    boolean c3Val= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);

            if (c1Val)
            {c1.setChecked(true);
                    }
            else{ 
                {c1.setChecked(false);
                    }
            };

             if(c2Val){
                c2.setChecked(true);
                } 
            else{ c2.setChecked(false);
             };

            if (c3Val){
                c3.setChecked(true);
             } 
            else{ c3.setChecked(false);
             }

    }


private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(c1.isChecked())
                savePreferences("CheckBox_Value",c1.isChecked());           if(c2.isChecked())
savePreferences("CheckBox_Value",c2.isChecked()         if(c3.isChecked())
savePreferences("CheckBox_Value",c3.isChecked());
finish();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't saved your checkboxes preferences.

```
private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
     editor.putBoolean(key, value);
     editor.commit();
    }
```

And remember to add unique key to each one checkboxes preferences

- CheckBox_Value1
- CheckBox_Value2
- CheckBox_Value3

And retrieve correct key while loading them.

Answer (score 1):

instead of same key for each checkbox, you should make unique key for each..

- checkBox_value_1
- checkBox_value_2